# how to get the value of multiple attr when clicked on

Tags: jquery-selectors

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td#crop').click(function() {
        $('img').each(function(){
          $('this').attr(id);
         alert(id);
        });

        })

});
```

I am trying to get the the value of the id of each image I click on but this is not working,Please help

Answer (score 0):

`this` should not be a string, and you need to save the value returned by `.attr()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#crop').click(function() {
        $('img').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr(id);
            alert(id);
        });
    });
});
```

#### Other cleanup:

- Added a missing semicolon (though that wasn't enough to break the code).
- Changed over-specifed selector `'td#crop'` to `'#crop'`, since there can be (at most) one element with a particular ID.